# Backing up datafile in Oracle database (Oracle 11g).

Tags: oracle11g, database-backups, rman

Apart from `RMAN` which tool or method can be used to backup datafiles while the database is up in Oracle 11g?

Comment: RMAN, dump data in file, snapshots, as well as complete volume replicas.

Comment: thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your DB is run in archivelog mode you can:
SQL> alter [database|tablespace|datafile] begin backup;
after this just copy you datafiles with "cp" command.

Do not forget to:
SQL>alter [database|tablespace|datafile] end backup;

Also there are some other techniques:
1) Some harware|storrage offer the possibility to take data-blocks snapshots 
2) logical backup with datapump.
3) in case you have standby you can just stop it consistently and copy datafiles.